# Как легко удалить из строки начальные символы такие как пробел, табуляция или символ новой строки и т.п. а также в конце?

Tags: c++, строки, консоль

Как легко удалить из строки начальные символы такие как пробел, табуляция или символ новой строки и т.п. а также в конце? У меня пользователь вводит строку с помощью консоли но он может ввести там пробелы, табуляцию, символ новой строки и т.п. и тогда ломается программа.

Comment: засовываешь строку в std::string. Там смотри в сторону find_first_not_of, find_last_of

Comment: что засовывать туда? у меня и так стринг есть пользователь ввел

Comment: `::boost::trim_left(str);` `::boost::trim_right(str);`

Comment: не работает это пишет error: ‘::boost’ has not been declared

Comment: Вот с помощью find_first_not_of ты сможешь найти первый символ который отличается от тех которые ты хочешь убрать сначала. С помощью find_last_of ты сможешь найти последний символ в конце, который не является пробелом/табом. Потом собираешь новую строчку согласно найденным итераторам.

Comment: @jeremy228 ну наверно потому что его подключить надо..

Comment: может кто нибудь дать рабочий ответ? что подключить и куда? мне не только пробел таб нужен но и новая строка и т.п.

Comment: Подключение буста тянет на отдельный вопрос...

Comment: всмсыле? я должен спрашивать кучу вопросов чтоб узнать как удалить из строки пробел таб новую линию и т.п.????

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216823/whats-the-best-way-to-trim-stdstring

Comment: спасибо ковадим уж лучше с переводчиком помучаюсь чутка чем тут тут ожидать нормального ответа

Comment: там прямо в вопросе уже есть готовый код для удаления начальных символов. А буст... это так, людям побаловаться, новые фичи потестить. Но для нормальной разработки... ни-ни-ни.

Comment: да всё работает оттуда попробовал спасибос